# Countdown timer needing to display seconds, currently just shows when finished

Tags: javascript

I've got this code:

```
var delta = data[1];
            var expire = new Date();
            expire.setSeconds(expire.getSeconds() + delta);
            var tick = function() {
                var now = new Date();

                if (now > expire) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            };

            var cancel = setInterval(function() {
                if (!tick()) {
                    clearInterval(cancel);
                }
            }, 1000);
```

data[1] is just the amount in seconds it needs to countdown.

Current it just resets when it is over, but I want to display the seconds remaining at every tick in console, how could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than rely on dates, which is definitely a possibility, if you're trying to keep this as simple as your specifications, I would just have a countdown variable.

```
var currentTime = delta;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
     if (currentTime == 0) {
         clearInterval(timer);
     }
     else {
         currentTime--;
         console.log(currentTime);
     }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Absolute legend! That solves all my issues at once. Relying on Date was a problem.

Comment: How is delta value getting populated?

Comment: delta is assigned in OP's question

Answer (score 0):

You can try returning the remaining time instead of `true`:

```
var remaining = 5e3;
var start = new Date();
var tick = function() {
    var diff = remaining - new Date() + +start;
    return diff < 0 ? false : diff;
};
var cancel = setInterval(function() {
    var diff = tick();
    if (diff === false) clearInterval(cancel);
    else console.log(diff);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It would be cleaner if `diff` is returned and `diff < 0` comparison used. Returning mixed types is a smell (even in a dynamically weak typed language)